# Create new contacts through Google People API

Tags: python, google-workspace, google-people-api

Is it possible to create google contacts using the Google People APIs?

I'm having trouble creating new contacts using the google APIs.

I'm searching for days and found the following information:

1 - Looks like the people API package comes to replace google contacts API

https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/google-people-api-now-supports-updates.html

2 - Many people are unable to create new contacts with python 3+ using gdata and atom packages.

3 - people API appears as recommended by Gsuite

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110?hl=pt-BR

I would like to know if anyone is creating new contacts using these Google People API.

Is a g suite email required?

How do I get access token?

I've done all the setup on google cloud platform (enable APIs and auth2), i have the json file, secret key and client id

edit:

I am managing to list my 50 contacts with this code, I am having to modify the blocks to create new contacts

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the People API.
    Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the People API
    print('List 50 connection names')
    results = service.people().connections().list(
        resourceName='people/me',
        pageSize=50,
        personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
    connections = results.get('connections', [])

    for person in connections:
        names = person.get('names', [])
        if names:
            name = names[0].get('displayName')
            print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please undelete your post, i have an answer, I understood your answer

Answer (score 5):

Since you already have auth working to list contacts, you should be able to do something like this to create one:

```
newContact = { "names": [{ "givenName": "John", "familyName": "Doe" }] }
result = service.people().createContact(body=newContact).execute()
```

The full definition of what can be in the body/person is [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person).

Comment: HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Remove the token file and try again

Comment: The scope you have in the code you posted here allows for creation of contacts.  Suggest what Jescanellas said, delete the token.pickle file and try again.

Comment: 400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:55487/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/898170200847-0g4lpn5frbkaaphrgv7dnutqcv4u8cc5.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=898170200847

Comment: localhost is not registered with your oauth client id.  How did it work the first time?  Go to the google cloud console (using the link provided in the error), find your client id and click on it if it doesn't load automatically, and add localhost to "Authorized redirect URIs".